# Consecutive events not stacking properly in calendar

Tags: calendarkit

[image]I would like the events to fill the entire horizontal space. These events have no overlap, but strangely they are offset. Any ideas what might be causing this, and how I can make the events take up the entire horizontal space?

I tried moving events around, but the weird offsetting occurs whenever events are back-to-back (not overlapping though). Also, this happened after completing the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJ63-_z1qg8) with no additional edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `eventGap` property to a non-zero value, e.g. as mentioned here:
https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit/pull/290

Comment: Please mark the question as resolved and let me know if this actually resolved your problem.

Comment: Hey, whose property is 'eventGap' exactly? Not sure where exactly I should be setting this property in my DayViewController.

Comment: Create a new `DayViewStyle` and set that property on a style, then just call `updateStyle` in your DayViewController. This property is responsible for event overlapping behavior: https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit/blob/master/Sources/DayViewController.swift#L78

Comment: For me DayViewStyle is not defined. I was able to figure it out from your hint though:

var calendarStyle = CalendarStyle()
calendarStyle.timeline.eventGap = 2.0
updateStyle(calendarStyle)

Thanks and resolved!

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was wrong about the style naming. I think it's worth to rename it to `DayViewStyle` as the CalendarKit is mainly about the `DayView` (you have to use other libraries to get Month or Year).